# Remove selection overlays when Editing UVs?

Tags: workflow, uv

How can I view my meshes UV's in *Edit Mode* without a selection overlay? I want to be able to view my object with its texture map (and edit it) without having highlighted vertices/edges/faces obscuring my view.

Comment: You can turn off vertex highlighting in Edit mode, if that's really what's bugging you

Comment: @Gwenn, how do you do that?

Comment: In the Transform menu (right-hand side), scroll down to 'Mesh Display' and uncheck everything

Comment: I think you could phrase your question more usefully `How can I view my meshes UV's without selection overlay`. Currently you are asking for a specific answer, rather then asking for a solution to the problem you describe.

Comment: @ideasman42, so it's not possible to edit UV's without entering edit mode?

Comment: @CharlesL, Correct - you **can't** edit UV's outside of editmode - unless you count using scripts or modifiers which can change UV's but I don't think this is what you are asking.

Comment: @ideasman42, in that case I will rephrase the question.

Comment: Personally I just flop in and out of edit mode a lot no matter what I'm doing… returning to object mode also updates the object mode undo list which can be handy…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get close (though you still need to keep Edit mode enabled):

1. In the 3D View's Properties region (<kbd>N</kbd>), go to the Display panel and enable the Only Render checkbox
2. In the Mesh Display panel, disable all of the overlays
3. Change to Edge Select mode in the 3D View (this at least hides the vertices, although the edges will still be highlighted).

And if you enable the UV Select Sync button in the UV editor (it's in the header), then the only edges you'll see in the 3D View are the ones that are selected in the UV editor.

Answer (score 3):

"Edit Mode" is required for UV editing. Here's a workaround for your display issue:

- Use the Array modifier to display a copy.
- Use [*View* > *Clipping Border*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html#view-clipping-border) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) to display only the array instance.
- Toggle the mesh cage as needed using [the [image: Applies modifier to editing cage in Edit mode] button in the modifier header](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface).

[image: Blender edit mode without mesh cage]

Comment: Not really a fan of this, while it works array modifier is slow for high poly objects and an unnecessary step if all you want to do is to tweak drawing options, which you can do without using the array modifier.

Comment: Indeed, but hiding the selection/vertices was specificity asked for, and can't be done using the display settings.